# Installed Git, not sure how to get it working

Tags: macos, terminal, git

Ive installed Git on my Mac (OS 10.7.5) and it seems to be successful (I get the successful installation message). But when I open my terminal and try some basic command line, eg" `git --version` I just get the message:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

This is what all the tutorials tell me to do to get started. I am at a loss as to what to do next.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely a compiler or a permission issue.

Searching google for "Illegal instruction: 4" returns many results. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177038/illegal-instruction-4-shows-up-in-os-x-lion):

I would suggest removing git, and simply installing Xcode because installing Xcode also installs a mac specific version of git.

You could alternately install using [homebrew](http://brew.sh)

Comment: Homebrew is the easiest option, IMHO.  You will still need to install Xcode, but you might be able to avoid its bloated CLI package.

Answer (score 1):

Not detracting from the command line approaches at all, [but you can also get the GUI version](http://mac.github.com).

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what Bill said: If you install the GUI version you can go to Advanced Preferences and it will give you an option to Install Command Line Tools. This will allow you to use both command line and the GUI, potentially resolving the compiler or permission issues you had.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that I found was to use Git 1.8.4.2, [which you can download here](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/detail?name=git-1.8.4.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg).